# RobotFramework - Help to understand - Multiline strings are different message

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am looking to compare two text files using RobotFramework. 
I get similar lines as shown below when there is a mismatch

```
Multiline strings are different:

--- first
+++ second
@@ -3,11 +3,11 @@
```

I understand that - denotes an old file and the + denotes the new file. 
I have trouble understanding the @@ -3,11  +3,11 @@ part.

Because , in the file , the difference is in line 10 of my file. 
I am not able to understand why it says 3 or 11

```
*** Settings ***
Library             SeleniumLibrary
Library         OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***

Read Text File

   ${Getfile1content}=      Get  File   convo1.txt

   ${Getfile2content}=      Get  File   convo2.txt

   Should be equal as strings   ${Getfile1content}     ${Getfile2content}
```

This is the code that I am using .

In my case, the difference is in Line 10 of the new file. It rightly isolates the lines and shows the difference but the actual numbers are confusing

Comment: Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81998/understanding-of-diff-output